# non-zero return code from aptitude command run via Ansible

Tags: ansible, debian

I'm getting an error when running the following Ansible task:

```
    - name: List packages to upgrade (1/2)
      shell: aptitude -q -F%p --disable-columns search "~U"
      register: updates
      changed_when: False
      when: ansible_os_family == 'Debian'
```

Error:

```
TASK [List packages to upgrade (1/2)] ********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [php7e]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "aptitude -q -F%p --disable-columns search \"~U\"", "delta": "0:00:00.828791", "end": "2021-06-23 10:31:26.849961", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2021-06-23 10:31:26.021170", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Noticed on another server, I don't get this error.  The server that doesn't have an issue has aptitude 0.7.4 and the one with the errors has aptitude  0.8.10.

Comment: what do you get when you manually run `aptitude -q -F%p --disable-columns search "~U"` on the server with error ? your `ansible` task looks correct. issue might be with the version of  `aptitude` itself.

Comment: I get no response from both servers.

Comment: now repeat the same test and after the command execution run `echo $?` on both servers.

Comment: @P.... both return 0.

Comment: this observation does't adds up with what ansible is reporting.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't run the original command prior to the echo.  It returns 0 on the server that is passing and 1 on the server that it is failing.

Comment: This observation fairly supports the answer by @umläute. in the sever with `rc=1` , aptitude is returning failure when it is not able to search the package.

Comment: check this https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html and search for `~U`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously `aptitude search` returns with an exit-code of `1` if no packages match the search term (in your case: if there are no upgradable packages)

as per the changelog:

> ```
> aptitude (0.7.6-1) unstable; urgency=low
> [...]
>       * [cmdline] "search" now exits with non-zero on errors or empty results
>         (Closes: #497299)
> ```

so: the observed behaviour is correct and expected.
you must update your ansible task accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I took over this ansible project and unfamiliar with what it is trying to do. Would you have any idea what searching `"~U"` would be trying to do?

Comment: it searches for installed packages for which an updated version is available in the repositories.

Comment: Got it. So in my case, there aren't any packages that need an update so it is failing. Would you know how to update this ansible task?